# Some part of Scss don't run in my browser

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to copy a background in css and I found this: https://codepen.io/alphardex/pen/RwrVoeL when I copy this in my css code I have a error about "invalid property name" in my browser so I create a Scss file like a css file and I have the same error. This is my Scss code:

```
@mixin sp-layout {
    @media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
        @content;
    }
}

@function random_range($min, $max) {
    $rand: random();
    $random_range: $min + floor($rand * (($max - $min) + 1));
    @return $random_range;
}

.stars {
    z-index: -1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120%;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.star {
    $star-count: 50;
    --star-color: var(--primary-color);
    --star-tail-length: 6em;
    --star-tail-height: 2px;
    --star-width: calc(var(--star-tail-length) / 6);
    --fall-duration: 9s;
    --tail-fade-duration: var(--fall-duration);

    position: absolute;
    top: var(--top-offset);
    left: 0;
    width: var(--star-tail-length);
    height: var(--star-tail-height);
    color: var(--star-color);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, currentColor, transparent);
    border-radius: 50%;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 6px currentColor);
    transform: translate3d(104em, 0, 0);
    animation: fall var(--fall-duration) var(--fall-delay) linear infinite, tail-fade var(--tail-fade-duration) var(--fall-delay) ease-out infinite;

    @include sp-layout {
        // For mobile performance, tail-fade animation will be removed QAQ
        animation: fall var(--fall-duration) var(--fall-delay) linear infinite;
    }

    @for $i from 1 through $star-count {
        &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        --star-tail-length: #{random_range(500em, 750em) / 100};
        --top-offset: #{random_range(0vh, 10000vh) / 100};
        --fall-duration: #{random_range(6000, 12000s) / 1000};
        --fall-delay: #{random_range(0, 10000s) / 1000};
        }
    }
}
star::before, star::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    left: calc(var(--star-width) / -2);
    width: var(--star-width);
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, currentColor, transparent);
    border-radius: inherit;
    animation: blink 2s linear infinite;
}

star::before {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

star::after {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}


    @keyframes fall {
        to {
            transform: translate3d(-30em, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    @keyframes tail-fade {
        0%, 50% {
            width: var(--star-tail-length);
            opacity: 1;
        }

        70%, 80% {
            width: 0;
            opacity: 0.4;
        }

        100% {
            width: 0;
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }

    @keyframes blink {
    50% {
        opacity: 0.6;
    }
}
```

The part of my browser doesn't detect is the loop for with variable $star-count, if someone can help me it's very kind.

Comment: This pen uses https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alphardex/aqua.css@master/dist/aqua.min.css Did you include it? Go to `Settings` -> `CSS` there you will find it.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand, I go in settings in my IDE ?

Comment: No, the Codepen settings (top right). There you find linked libraries and stuff like that. The scss in the codepen depends on the source I've linked.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a comment, your linked Codepen uses an external css file that is required to make the effect work.

Add this at the beginning of your scss file and it will work:

```
@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alphardex/aqua.css@master/dist/aqua.min.css");
```

You find external linked files in Codepen at the top right under settings

[image: Codepen Settings location]
[image: External linked css file]

This doesn't apply here but you should also check the `JS` section in Codepen settings. Sometimes there is also an external JavaScript library linked.